# How to access non-first matches with xpath in Selenium RC?

Tags: python, xpath, selenium, selenium-rc

I have 20 labels in my page:

```
In [85]: sel.get_xpath_count("//label")
Out[85]: u'20'
```

And I can get the first one be default:

```
In [86]: sel.get_text("xpath=//label")
Out[86]: u'First label:'
```

But, unlike the xpath docs I've found, I'm getting an error trying to subscript the xpath to get to the second label's text:

```
In [87]: sel.get_text("xpath=//label[2]")
ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (216, 0))

ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (1186, 0))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/me/<ipython console> in <module>()

/Users/me/selenium.pyc in get_text(self, locator)
   1187         'locator' is an element locator
   1188         """
-> 1189         return self.get_string("getText", [locator,])
   1190 
   1191 

/Users/me/selenium.pyc in get_string(self, verb, args)
    217 
    218     def get_string(self, verb, args):
--> 219         result = self.do_command(verb, args)
    220         return result[3:]
    221 

/Users/me/selenium.pyc in do_command(self, verb, args)
    213         #print "Selenium Result: " + repr(data) + "\n\n"

    214         if (not data.startswith('OK')):
--> 215             raise Exception, data
    216         return data
    217 

Exception: ERROR: Element xpath=//label[2] not found
```

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

**`(//label)[2]`**

The XPath expression you are currently using:

> **`//label[2]`**

means:

Select every `label` element in the document that is the second `label` child of its parent. Chances are that every `label` in the document is just the first and only `label` child of its parent. In such a case the above expression selects nothing.